# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript pause execution rest of the code until close window

Tags: asp.net, popupwindow, clientscript

I'm using

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
```

to open popup windows.

I have some code lines after this line. But I need to execute those code after closing the popup. Not immediately.
Any solution?

Button Click event:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string queryString = "WebForm2.aspx";
            string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "');";

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);

                ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;

        }
```

Button click Opens pop up page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick` like this:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"
    OnClientClick="javascript:return myFunction()" OnClick="btnSave_Click" /> 

    function myFunction() {

             if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Continue ?")) 
             {
                 return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 return false;
             }
      }
```

OR from code behind try this:-

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "myFunction();", true);
```

OR

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction();</script>", false);
```

Comment: I have tried below options. But doesn't work.
string queryString = "WebForm4.aspx";
string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", newWin, true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert", newWin, false);

Comment: Third option open the new window and same time executes the rest of code before close the window. But I expect is want to pause the execution of rest part of code until close popup window

Comment: @Piratheeban why dont you use `OnClientClick` ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I have an aspx with backend code, I need to pop up the specific page.

Comment: @Piratheeban please post your code with complete logic :) Update your question